# NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. Toast and Event manager

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, toast

Can somebody help me with this? blocks of codes in the picture is not my code, I don't know where is coming from. and this error is showing on random... I can't find way to reproduce this bug :S

[image]

Comment: Please post code and errors as plain formatted text snippets, images of code and errors are pretty but they can be more difficult to read and more importantly they are not searchable or copy/pastable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, provide your code so we can tell where the issue is coming from. Otherwise, it all are guesses.

Comment: i don't know where issue is coming from :S that Is the problem. because I cant find this code from error in my code :S i searched entire project but there is no suck code :S

Comment: i tought maybe somebody had simular issue so i can at least try to find where is the problem :S

Comment: There's likely also a stacktrace for this error, you may need to click "X frames collapsed" (or whatever) to view the full trace. Drill down far enough and you should start hitting your code.